# Uploaded images with malicious code in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, image-processing, amazon-s3

I have a custom php web application where users will be able to upload images. 
I know that there is a security concern with image files as a hacker can add malicious code to them and trigger them through the url of the image file.

So I'm no longer storing images in the web server and uploading them directly into Amazon S3. I was wondering if it is still possible for a hacker to achieve the same results with a malicious image even if the image files are stored in a completely separate place like Amazon S3.

Comment: How does somebody trigger code from the URL of an image file? They could store a script as a file with an image extension and then run the script, but if your code is referencing images via an `IMG` tag, then it will not execute code. Could you please clarify your concerns, preferably with a reference to an explanation of the exploit?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm pretty sure that he's talking about content-type sniffing, where you can embed code in an image, the web browser will take a look at the first bytes, and if it considers that it's code, then it'll assume that it's code and it'll execute its contents.

Comment: At a high level there are two types of vulnerabilities with images, server-side and client-side. On Server-side, hackers have exploited vulnerabilities in software like imagemagick if you are processing the image, irrespective of where you store it, so your server gets compromised. On client-side, it would generally be a browser vulnerability if you are just serving image with proper content-type. Validate your input file and keep your server software and libraries patched.

Answer (score 1):

If you upload files into S3 then there would be no need to worry about the server side exploits like RCE as it is an object storage which won't be executed, but you need to take care of client side vulnerabilities like XSS...
i.e., even in your case of image upload, attacker cannot harm the server side setup directly by exploiting Unrestricted file upload but he can embed client side script into the image and exploit... as @dy10 mentioned, setting the proper content-type would help...